# SED not removing last double quote from every line

Tags: sed, csv, csv-simple

I have a CSV that was exported with double quotes around every header and value and I need them gone but without removing double quotes that might actually exist as values. For example:

```
"HEADER1","HEADER2","HEADER3","HEADER4","HEADER5"
"SOME_ID_0X0","SOME_ID_1X2","false","Some blob value with "double quotes" inside of it"
"SOME_ID_0X0","SOME_ID_1X2","false","Some blob value with "double quotes" inside of it"
"SOME_ID_0X0","SOME_ID_1X2","false","Some blob value with "double quotes" inside of it"
```

I can remove the first `"` from every line with the following

```
$ sed -i.bak 's/^"//g' $1
```

And I can remove all the ones in between with this:

```
$ sed -i.bak 's/","/,/g' $1
```

And finally I thought I could remove the last `"` in every line with this:

```
$ sed -i.bak 's/"$//g' $1
```

But it's not working. Could I accomplish this entire task in one line?

**UPDATE**
I used [this website](https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php) to paste my data for hidden characters and here was the results

[image]

It appears some of the comment may be accurate but I don't know what that means I need to change still. Also **is there a a clean way to check if the CSV has these quotes before attempting to remove them?** Perhaps even just qualifying that the first character is a quote?

Comment: Perhaps `"` is not really the last character on each line (either because of trailing whitespace, or even because of DOS CRLF line endings)?

Comment: That actually works fine for me when I copy & paste your data into a file; I'll hazard a guess that your **real** data differs from what you showed us, and that there's either a space or some other non-printing character in the last position before the \n ..

Comment: have you tried  `dos2unix` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dos2unix` to convert DOS to UNIX text file format

```
dos2unix $1
```

You could combine all 3 `sed` as:

```
 sed -i 's/^"//g;s/","/,/g;s/"$//g' $1

SOME_ID_0X0,SOME_ID_1X2,false,Some blob value with "double quotes" inside of it
SOME_ID_0X0,SOME_ID_1X2,false,Some blob value with "double quotes" inside of it
SOME_ID_0X0,SOME_ID_1X2,false,Some blob value with "double quotes" inside of it
```

Using `AWK` :

```
awk -F ',' -v OFS=',' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) sub(/^\"/,"",$i) sub (/\"$/,"",$i); print $0}' 1$

HEADER1,HEADER2,HEADER3,HEADER4,HEADER5
SOME_ID_0X0,SOME_ID_1X2,false,Some blob value with "double quotes" inside of it
SOME_ID_0X0,SOME_ID_1X2,false,Some blob value with "double quotes" inside of it
SOME_ID_0X0,SOME_ID_1X2,false,Some blob value with "double quotes" inside of it
```

- `sub(/^\"/,"",$i)` removes the `"` at start of each field.
- `sub(/\"$/,"",$i)` removes the `"` at end of each field.

Comment: You can do "dos2unix" in sed: `sed 's/\r$//' file`, so removing trailing quote is `sed 's/\r$//; s/"$//'` -- should work even if file has unix format.